validateToolBarItem not called
In my mac application, validateToolBarItem: isn't called after a row of a NSTableView is dropped.
The docs list events that don't trigger toolbar validation, but mouseUp: isn't one of them. So I'm not sure why the toolbar doesn't validate after that a table row is dropped, since this is associated with a mouse up event.
To force validation, I call setWindowsNeedUpdate: on NSApp within tableView:acceptDrop:row:dropOperation:.
I wonder if there is a better solution.
